Updating records using SQL with Excel
I'm trying to use SQL with VBA to update an Excel worksheet.
My macro updates five worksheets in the same file (Review, Used, Road, Inspec, and Misc). It runs SQL to update each worksheet based on some criteria.
I'm trying to put an "X" in the TMP column and a code in the TMP2 column (on the MatchedLines worksheet) for the records.
'closing the connection from the previous SELECT query.  The SELECT query is first and runs fast with no problems.
            dbRS.Close
            dBcn.Close
            
        
'          ADD X TO TMP COLUMN and S to TMP2 column FOR REVIeW RECORDS
           Do Until ActiveSheet.Name = "MatchedLines"
                DoEvents
                Workbooks(ThisBook).Worksheets("MatchedLines").Activate
            Loop
            
            dBcn.Open dbconn
            
            vsql = ""
            vsql = "UPDATE [MatchedLines$] M " _
                & " SET M.[TMP] = 'X', [TMP2] = 'S' " _
                & "WHERE M.[RO_ID] IN " _
                & " (SELECT DISTINCT [RO_ID] FROM [Review$])"
            
            dbRS.Open vsql, dBcn

When the macro runs the second query, it bogs down and freezes Excel.
I usually use Task Manager to close Excel at this time.
The purpose is to "mark" these records in the MatchedLines worksheet, so subsequent queries do select the same records.
Is there something wrong with the SQL?
Would a DELETE query be better and remove these records from the MatchedLines worksheet?

How large is your data in the worksheets? Excel is possibly hanging because the SQL is trying to deal with the multiple worksheets and updating an entire worksheet at once.

Hey, if your goal is to to update the worksheets and not making permanent changes to the SQL DB, you may be able to use Power Query for instead of macros. Have you tried it?

Any reason to not use formulas?

@neutronHacker.........The MatchedLines sheet may have 45,000 rows.  The macros splits those records onto 5 sheets.  After the first 4 select, I'm trying to update the MatchedLines sheet, so those records do not appear on any other sheet.  That's the goal anyway.  Thanks....

@nkalvi............Thanks............I have never used Power Query.  SQL works pretty good on Excel worksheets but this is the first time we are updating a worksheet with Excel.  The current dataset is less than 3000 records although it can grow to over 45,000 records by the end of the month.......

@ike..........I don't think formulas is the solution,  The number of records each day is different and as I mentioned I'm trying to split the records onto 5 different worksheets.  Marking the records is a way to ensure they only appear on 1 worksheet and not on multiple worksheets.  Thanks

Make it in a simple way.

Create a Connection

   Dim cnx As New ADODB.Connection
   Dim CONSTR As String
   CONSTR = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & "; Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";"
   cnx.ConnectionString = CONSTR
   cnx.Open

2) then execute the update query on this connection object
dim vsqk as string 
vsql = ""
            vsql = "UPDATE [MatchedLines$] M " _
                & " SET M.[TMP] = 'X', [TMP2] = 'S' " _
                & "WHERE M.[RO_ID] IN " _
                & " (SELECT DISTINCT [RO_ID] FROM [Review$])"
cnx.execute vsql

I think it will work for you.
Thank you.
